# I want to determine the length of each word String and taken those when length of more than 10

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME FROM PERSONS WHERE ................
```

**RESULT**

```
**Anun Azganun
John Smith
Tigran Shahnazaryan*
```

Example LENGTH(SHAHNAZARYAN) > 10 then select this row*

Comment: So `Tigran Shahnazaryan` is one row and you want to include it if any of the words in that row are greater then 10 in length?

Comment: I deleted **Please help me** from your post - please see the rules for the forum. Then, you say `select firstname, lastname ...` but in your comment to Nilsman you wrote "firstname lastname in one column." So it seems it's all in one column, why do you write `select firstname, lastname` in your question? This is not a complicated thing; is it really that hard to be accurate? If you can't get something like this right, when you are asking others for help no less, I don't think you will do too well in the IT industry.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME FROM PERSONS WHERE LENGTH(LASTNAME) > 10;
```

Or, if you want single string for name and surname try
    `SELECT FIRSTNAME || ' ' || LASTNAME FROM PERSONS WHERE LENGTH(LASTNAME) > 10;`

Comment: FIRSTNAME LASTMAE IN ONE COLUMN

Comment: I don't understand. There are no firstname and lastname columns in table, but column firstandlastname is? Then you should write something like `SELECT firstandlastname FROM persons WHERE LENGTH(SUBSTR(firstandlastname, INSTR(firstandlastname, ' ', -1) + 1)) > 10`